# How do I know that the transition animation is finish when push a new page

Tags: flutter

When push a new page, I load the data in initState. This resulted in stuttering during the transition animation. This problem is particularly serious on Android.

In react native, I can use

```
InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions (() => {
           // ... do some time-consuming operations ...
});
```

Is there a similar method in flutter. Let me know that the transition animation is finish?

Comment: The PageRouteBuilder can manage animations, so you will find how to check for animation completion inside it. Maybe you will find how to do it here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: [TransitionRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionRoute-class.html) has `animation` and `controller` properties that you can use for transition "listening"

Answer (score 8):

In your destination page you can get an instance of `ModalRoute`.
`ModalRoute` has an `animation` property exposing `addStatusListener` to react to animation lifecycle events.

The following exemple may help you :

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var route = ModalRoute.of(context);

    // Defining an internal function to be able to remove the listener
    void handler(status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        print('Animation completed !');
        route.animation.removeStatusListener(handler);
      }
    }

    route.animation.addStatusListener(handler);
..
```